# Spring JPA - Postgres - Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to run a Spring Application with Postgres and JPA

My POM is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My application.properties is:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/estudos
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
```

And when I try to run my app this error came to me:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
```

Comment: Are you sure `org.postgresql:postfreslql` is getting pulled down by Maven?

Comment: You properties and POM file look fine. Problem should be from maven. Add try to run without `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver`. In my app I didn't have it but still works fine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was INTELLIJ CACHE....after I closed intellij and reload at Maven persepctive

Hours missed on in

Comment: You are so right! I did File>Invalidate Caches/Restart... and my problem went away!! Thanks for posting